# How to not move permissions on fileserver file move

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-permissions, netapp

I have a problem with a NetApp file server with Windows XP clients.

The files are on a single SAN drive. The users regularly move files from `\\storage\share` to their personal folder at e.g. `\\storage\myfolder`. This is fine so far, but it becomes a problem when they move files from `\\storage\share` to `\\storage\secretCompany` and add some secret information to the file. The permissions for the file are still the same as they were in *share*, hence everyone with the permissions to share can now see this file in *secretCompany*.

Is there any way to prevent Windows from copying permissions and just always use the target permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From Microsoft..**

You can modify how Windows Explorer handles permissions when objects are moved in the same NTFS volume. As mentioned, when an object is moved within the same volume, the object preserves its permissions by default. However, if you want to modify this behavior so that the object inherits the permissions from the parent folder, modify the registry as follows:

1. **Click Start**, **click Run**, **type regedit**, and then press **ENTER**.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer**
3. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

   **Value name: MoveSecurityAttributes**

   **Data type: DWORD**

   **Value data: 0**
4. Exit Registry Editor.
5. Make sure that the user account that is used to move the object has the Change Permissions permission set. If the permission is not set, grant the Change Permissions permission to the user account.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Good info. Here is the KB article describing the registry value MoveSecurityAttributes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316